# Audiokit release supporting Swift 3.3

Tags: audiokit

With Xcode 9.3 out, there is only the choice of swift lang version 3.3 and 4.1. I have some projects that need to stay in 3.3 but i cannot find a release of Audiokit that supports 3.3. Does anyone know if there is a release we can use against swift 3.3?
cheers
steph

Answer (score 0):

There's no trail of which version of AudioKit supports exactly 3.3, but its supported Swift 3 as of AudioKit 3.4:

https://github.com/AudioKit/AudioKit/releases/tag/v3.4

all the way up to AudioKit 4.1

https://github.com/AudioKit/AudioKit/releases/tag/v4.1

I'm guessing 4.1 will work for Swift 3.3

Comment: Thanks Aurelius. 4.1 does build to 3.3. My bad, Xcode needed a completely clean project to build properly. Btw, thanks for the quick response to Apple's updates.